# getting data from postgres to php to html (with ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql

I am using ajax to call a php script which gets data from my postgres DB.
In php, my code is:

```
$sql = "select * from processWebRequest($1)";
$res = pg_prepare($dbconn, "interaction_insert_query", $sql);
$res = pg_execute($dbconn, "interaction_insert_query", array($req));
$myarray = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc( $res )/*pg_fetch_row($contests)*/) {
  $myarray[] = $row;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($myarray);//
```

The problem is that back in ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../php/recordInteraction.php",
    type: 'GET',
    data : pObject,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response,textStatus,jqXHR){
```

The response variable seems to hold more and more data.  I know each query returns at most two rows, but when I load the file in the debugger the response variable is an array with 25 rows.

Seems like I need to flush something, I just have no idea what.

Can someone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your endpoint directly and debug your database query to see the results you get. It appears you're getting back 25 rows.

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc( $res )/*pg_fetch_row($contests)*/) {
var_dump( $row );
  $myarray[] = $row;
}
```

OR

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc( $res )/*pg_fetch_row($contests)*/) {
    $myarray[] = $row;
}
var_dump( $myarray );
die;
```